# How to calculate word similarity based on transformer?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, word-embedding, transformer-model

I know I can train word embedding in Tensorflow or Gensim, then I can retrieve top N most similar words for a target word. Given that transformer is now the main stream model for text representation, I want to know whether there is a better way to compute word similarity than Word Embedding. In genesim, I can do:

```
sims = model.wv.most_similar('computer', topn=10)
```

For example, if I use sentence transformer to compute:

https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/LaBSE

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
sentences = ["This is an example sentence", "Each sentence is converted"]

model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/LaBSE')
embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
print(embeddings)
```

Then use this embedding to compute similarity, would that work for word similarity, if I treat any word as a 'sentence'? Or I use Bert embedding model:

https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html

I feed a word like 'computer' as input to get an embedding, then compute its topN similarity. Does this make sense? or it won't work better than embedding trained without involving transformer?

Comment: How do you plan to compute the top-k similarity? Are you storing embeddings for each (singular) word of your vocabulary in a vector storage?

Comment: Ideally, I can do something like what genism library does. I train a word embedding or transformer model, then I can write a function to get topN similarity words. If I use genism, it already provided the most_similar(topN) function.

Comment: yes, Gensim provides this, but Huggingface does not. In this case, you would have to be a bit more specific, otherwise this question is way too broad to be answered on Stackoverflow IMO.

Comment: @dennlinger I read that Word2Vec are static embedding but transformer models are dynamic embedding. Does that mean Bert produce different word embedding in each different sentence for the same word like 'bank'? According to the paper 'Attention is all you need', the input to the encoder is firstly the Word Embedding plus positional encoding.  Does this Word Embedding mean static embedding and how to understand the dynamic embedding in relation to the Word Embedding as the transformer input?

Comment: Hi! I am also interested in the answer to this question. @marlon